# Get a stream of documents from Firebase with Flutter in Null-safe way

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, null-safety

I'm a flutter null-safe noob. I used the code below, but I am getting this error:

```
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

This does seem like a null-safe issue but then again it may be that one has to do this getting a stream of documents different in null safety.

```
class DataService {

final _dataStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance; 

  Stream <List<Shop>> listAllShops() {    
    return _dataStore.collection('shops')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Shop.fromJson(document.data())) <<< error comes here
        .toList());
  }
}
```

I have tried putting a ? in various places but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you don't show it, the `Shop.fromJson` constructor likely takes a `Map<String, dynamic>` type. A non-nullable type. The `data` function referenced in `document.data()` returns a nullable type. You just need to promote the nullable type to a non-nullable type.

This can be easily done with the bang operator `!` if you're sure the data will not be null:

```dart
Stream <List<Shop>> listAllShops() {    
    return _dataStore.collection('shops')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Shop.fromJson(document.data()!))
        .toList());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```dart
document.data()
```

`document.data()` can be `null` which is why you see an error. If you're sure that it will never be `null`, just use

```dart
document.data()!
```

Comment: This is most definitely *not* the issue.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore My bad, I used `!` before data call. The issue was this actually

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Ahh you also posted that in a new answer